# Set proof: $ A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C \implies A \cup B \subseteq C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that $ A, B, C$ are sets, and that $ A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C \implies A \cup B \subseteq C$.

I have done this so far but I don't know if it is enough as a proof:
Suppose $x \in  A \cup B$. Then $ x \in A \cup B \implies x \in C$. So $x \in A$ or $ x \in B \implies x \in C$. Then $x \in A \implies x \in C$ and $x \in B \implies x \in C$. So it must be that $x \in A \subseteq C$ and $x \in B \subseteq C$.

Comment: In these kinds of proofs, you want to use $\iff$ only to prove equality of sets. For subset relations like this one, you are going to use $\implies$.

Comment: @GFauxPas so now is all completed?

Comment: See also: [How to formally show "if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \cup B \subseteq C$"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567389)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proof by contrapositive:

suppose $A \cup B \not\subseteq C$.

Then $\exists x \in A \cup B$, such that $x \notin C$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $x \in A$.  Thus $\exists x \in A$, such that $x \notin C$.  Therefore it does not hold that $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C$.

So $A \cup B \not\subseteq C \implies \lnot (A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C)$.

Comment: You're welcome.  The forward proof is a little akward, but contrapositive is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$. The union operator is monotonous and so by hypothesis, 
$A\cup B\subseteq C\cup B\subseteq C\cup C.$ But $C\cup C=C$. Done.